# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted on fs.copy

Tags: node.js, node.js-fs

I have a Node script which should serve to copy files from a local machine to a directory which is a network drive mounted on the computer.

```
public async remoteCopyFiles(source: string, destination: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
        await fs.promises.access(source, fs.constants.R_OK);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Read error', error);
    }

    try {
        await fs.promises.access(destination, fs.constants.W_OK);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Write error', error);
    }

    await fs.promises.cp(source, destination, { recursive: true });
}
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile '/home/user/MyProject/dist/font.woff2' -> '/mnt/NetworkUnit/font.woff2'] 

errno: -1,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  path: '/home/user/MyProject/dist/font.woff2',
  dest: '/mnt/NetworkUnit/font.woff2'
```

The strange thing is that if I copy/paste the files manually to the target directory, it does it without any problems and does not throw any permissions error.

Am I missing something along the way?

Thanks

Comment: is the nodejs app running under the same user you are using for manual copy (check with `console.log(process.env.USER)`? also it seems like the destination is a network mounted drive... so it happens that some filesystems might have restrictions on actions performed by scripts ...  

another option could be to try another library -> `fs-extra` and the `copy` function ... should be more compatible with different filesystems ....  last resort could be to try to spawn a child process

Comment: In principle both the user who runs the Node script and the user who manually copies the files to the mounted network folder is the same, yes. I will check if the network drive has any restrictions on the execution of scripts and I will also try to use the fs-extra library. I will keep you informed.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried with the fs-extra library and got exactly the same error. I still need to check with my systems team to see if it is some server configuration. I will keep you informed.